# Google sheets query error: QUERY has only 3 arguments, but got 4

Tags: google-sheets-formula

This is the sintax for google sheets query

```
QUERY(data, query, [headers])
```

Here is my formula

```
QUERY({TimeclockPunches},"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 WHERE Col2<>'' AND Col5='Supervisor'",0)
```

When I add the [headers], which is an optional argument (but needed to prevent my query from displaying wrong results), the formula is underlined in red with the following error: [image 1 link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7ScL.png)

[image]

"QUERY only takes 3 arguments, but this is argument number 4".

2nd screenshot, different sheet, similar formula: [image 2 link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvRzL.png)

[image]

Despite the error message, the formula and spreadsheets are working as intended.

Why is detecting the [header] as 4th argument? Suggestions on how to clean this error?

(I researched it, and couldn't find any resolution, but maybe someone here knows better)

Comment: Please share the complete formula

Comment: @idfurw , hi, the formula is posted in the code section, not sure if it's visible (sorry I am new). Also I pasted it here: 

QUERY({TimeclockPunches},"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 WHERE Col2<>'' AND Col5='Supervisor'",0

The picture of the same formula is zoomed in only to show the red line marking the query with an error.

Comment: There is one more closing bracket in the screenshot.

Comment: @idfurw , thanks for asking. For privacy, I had to reproduce the error on an empty sheet. See new screenshot. 
Similar query, within an IF condition, causing the same error. Consider that the formula and query are working, but I would like to know about this error. Does it look like a bug?

Comment: It seems like a bug with the `IF` and `{}`. When both of them present, it cannot count the correct number of argument but the output is correct. You should better remove `{}` and select with column letter.

Comment: @idfurw ok, thank you. I changed the formula without {} and no more warning message.

=if(A1<>"",QUERY(A1:D9, "SELECT A WHERE B<>'' AND B='a' ",0),"") . 

If you post your question, I'll mark it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a bug with the `IF` and `{}`.

When both of them present, it cannot count the correct number of argument but the **output is correct**.

You should better remove `{}` and `select` with column letter in `QUERY`.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, thanks.  This is a good way around this bug for now.